# How does autolink:map work

Tags: android, textview

I am using **antroid:autoLink="map"   attribute of TextView** to Go to map and find the address associated with that textview.

But its is behaving stragely and **finding only some addresses**. Here is the code what I am trying:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewautoLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/autolinktext"
        android:autoLink="map"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my **strings.xml**

```
strings.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="autolinktext">1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043 </string>
</resources>
```

**Issue is:**

Suppose I am writing the above string i.e. 
**1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043**
then its working fine and textView gets blue in colour and when I click onit it searches the address on Map.

When I change this address to : **1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mumbai, IN**
then also it shows the same thing and tries to search the address but since the address is wrong it couldnt find it. Its OK.

But when I write other address like: **600 Band Stand, Mumbai, IN**
Then

> 1) the textview isnt in blue color
>
> 2) Its doesn't seem to be clickable
>
> 3) and since it is not clickable it doesn't find the address.

I am searching google but am not getting any  reason for this behaviour.
Also I want to know that

> Is there any format for writing this map address?
>
> Also how android knows that the address is valid or not by just
>   writing the address in String as I have written the same address in
>   the same format just changed the String and the result is that one
>   address is clickable and other is not.

Please Help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is the comment picked from the matcher

1. look for a 1 - 5 digit number for a street number (no support for 'One Microsoft Way')
2. ignore if preceded by '#', Suite, Ste, Rm
3. look for two or more words (up to 5? North Frank Lloyd Wright Blvd)
   note: "The Circle at North Hills St." has six words, and a lower 'at' -- allow at, by, of, in, the, and, ... ?
4. if a word starts with a lowercase letter, no match
   allow: , . - # / (for 1/2) ' "
5. look for one or two delimiters to represent possible 2nd addr line and city name
   look for either full state name, or state two letters, and/or zip code (5 or 9 digits)
6. now look for street suffix, either in full or abbreviated form, with optional 's' if there's an asterisk

Source : CacheBuilder.cpp. For further info you could check the exact algorithm in CacheBuilder::FindPartialAddress of webviewcore

As far as i see from code only 
street names ending in LleY , NneX, RCade, VEnue, LAMEDA, aYoU and so on ... are matched. 
In your case **Band stand** does not match the street name ending that is common in US

Comment: Thanks for the reply...You mean to say that I have to write the address according to US address structure as in other countries the street names are different and also there is no street numbers in every country.

Comment: Thanks for ur time nandeesh ...I just wanted to know  from where you got the above information(i.e your answer)...Can u just give me a link

Comment: the findaddress is done from webview. So you need android code. you can see the cachebuilder.cpp here http://bit.ly/zcY1q2. FindPartialAddress is the function name. longstreetnames is the array that has ending letters used to match street

Comment: Thanks nandeesh that really nice