# How to check whether the received message is an address, a number or a simple text in android programmatically

Tags: android

I am making a messaging application in which user can send or receive a message through my App but I want a functionality that if user received an address through SMS then he can click on that and transferred to Google Map and If user received a Mobile Number or telephone number then he can able to call on that number. I implemented all the functionality related to messaging but failed to check that on the behalf of above information. Please suggest me the right solution regarding to the subject.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `TextView` to display the messages, you can use the attribute [`autoLink`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink) on the `TextView` element of the layout XML. This will automatically create links when street addresses, phone numbers and e-mail adresses are detected. You're less in control, but you get a lot for free!

From the documentation:

```
android:autoLink

Controls whether links such as urls and email addresses are automatically found and converted to clickable links. The default value is "none", disabling this feature.
```

**Update**

If you want all supported types to be `autoLinked` you can use `android:autoLink="all"`. A concrete example to create auto links for `email`, `phone`, and `map` (separated by the `|` character):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="email|phone|map" >
</TextView>
```

It is important to notice that the `autoLink` for `map` is not perfect. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624649/autolink-for-map-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767721/android-autolink-attribute-in-textview-behaving-strangely) for more details.

Comment: this autolink attribute is responsible for numbers, emailaddresses but how we force it to recognize the addresses which will be redirected to Google Map.

Comment: what's with the down vote? anyway, see the updated answer for how to use `autoLink` for `map` as well.

Comment: Sorry for it, I don't want to do that but it happened coincidentally. I m really Sorry for that and your answer is right and I am very thankful to you. If possible I will increase it, I assure you.

Comment: Ok, no problem, you can just click the down arrow again to undo it :-) I'm glad to help!